# what are the fields of the packet generated by pktgen linux utility?

Tags: linux, packet-capture, dpdk

I tried to capture the packets sent by *packtgen* but I wasn't able to do that.
I am curious what the packet generated by packet generator looks like.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: DPDK pktgen generates ethernet-ip-tcp packets. Can you please make your question clear?

Comment: Thanks for making question clear, please share the command used for capturing packets from dpdk-pktgen

Comment: waiting for your updates

Comment: marking as needs improvement since there are no udaptes from @domidov

Answer (score 0):

DPDK Pktgen allows to capture packets in run time from a desired port or multiple ports. To achieve the same follows the steps as

1. Launch the Pktgen tool in interactive mode
2. to enable the capture option execute `enable [portlist] capture`
3. all packets received on the interface will be capture with unique file name (port number appened)
4. To disable/stop the capture execute `disable [portlist] capture`

[link to capture mode in GUI](https://pktgen-dpdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running.html)